# How to search inbox using zend mail

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, zend-mail

The following is a function from zend_mail_protocol_imap.  i read that to search emails, I would want to override it using zend_mail_storage_imap (which is what I'm using now to grab email from gmail).  I copy and pasted the following function into zend_mail_storage_imap, but I'm having issues with the params.  I can't find documentation on what to use for the array $params.  I initially thought it was the search term before reading it more thoroughly.  I'm out of ideas.  Here's the function...

```
/**
 * do a search request
 *
 * This method is currently marked as internal as the API might change and is not
 * safe if you don't take precautions.
 *
 * @internal
 * @return array message ids
 */
public function search(array $params)
{                                                                                    
    $response = $this->requestAndResponse('SEARCH', $params);
    if (!$response) {
        return $response;
    }

    foreach ($response as $ids) {
        if ($ids[0] == 'SEARCH') {
            array_shift($ids);
            return $ids;
        }
    }
    return array();
}
```

Initially I thought this would do the trick...

```
$storage = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($imap);

$searchresults = $storage->search('search term');
```

Here's the error message:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1
>   passed to
>   Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap::search() must
>   be an array, string given, called
>   in...

But nope, I need to send the info in an array.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Bob, did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing now.

Comment: Nope, but I found similar functionality by rewriting code from zend_mail to the php_imap library:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$searchresults = $storage->search(array('search term'));
```

Comment: I tried this and got a different fatal error "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap::search() in..."

Answer (score 0):

this is how i did it

```
$searchTerm = 'TEXT ' . $searchTerm ;
$searchresults = $storage->search(array($searchTerm));
```

Search parameter for zend is same as of imap_search . Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php for further reference .

Answer (score 0):

there is (still) no search function in storage\imap, that function is actually in the protocol class.

to have a search in storage\imap add this function:

```
public function search($params = null) {
    return $this->protocol->search($params);
}
```

now you should be able to call like this

```
$storage->search(array('SUBJECT "test","UNSEEN",'FROM "santa@northpole.org"'));
```

and the result should be a list of ids/uids of the messages, just like imap_search. 
imho this function or a getter for protocol should be in the storage class, but it isnt.